# CSS GRID неправильное поведение

Tags: html, css, grid

есть грид родитель:

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(10, auto);
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в нём элементы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

цель, сделать мозайку, первый ряд ниже, второй выше, третий ниже, четвертый выше

всё вроде бы почти готово, но как только я задаю `grid-row: 5/10` последнему элементу чтобы закрыть грид, ряды ломаются:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Нужен пример кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

.block:first-child, .block:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: 1/6;
}

.block:nth-child(2), .block:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: 1/5;
}

.block:nth-child(5), .block:nth-child(7) {
  grid-row: 6/10;
}

.block:nth-child(6), .block:last-child {
  grid-row: 5/10;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```